# fprintd-verify always returns verify no match done Kubuntu 22.04 acer spin 5

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fingerprint, ubuntu-22.04

I recently installed kubuntu 22.04 on my acer spin 5 and tried to make the fingerprint sensor work. I managed to figure out that libfprint require me to swipe my finger across the sensor (which windows 11 does not, its a touch not a swipe).
After I enrolled my fingerprint using fprintd-enroll everything seemed to work, no errors. Except when I tried to fprintd-verify, I can't get anything else than verify no match done.

I did some research and found that I was not the only one having issues, but I haven't found a solution that works for me.

Here is the sensor : Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04f3:0c4f Elan Microelectronics Corp. ELAN:Fingerprint

Using libfprint-2-2:
Installed: 1:1.94.3+tod1-0ubuntu2~22.04.03

Can anyone help me ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have the exact same issue... have you found any answer by chance?

Comment: @Froggo unfortunately no. I tried a lot of ways and neither of them worked. I will try a different distro at some point, maybe this will be it.